# model.load_weights() does not restore the internal states of the optimizer

Tags: keras

I want to restore the optimizer's states after building my model. (not using `load_model()`)

I know that `load_model()` can handle the optimizer's status, but unfortunately, my model uses a lot of custom layers. 
Thus, I want to build my model by the code and after that, I want to restore all of the training statuses.
Weights in layers can be restored by using `model.load_weights()`, but optimizer's status is not recovered.

Comment: When saving the model, I use ``model.save()``.

Comment: Using custom layers is not a problem with load_model, just use the custom_objects parameter.

Comment: I also know that and it is one option, but are there any other approach to load all of the weights after building a model?

Comment: What is the problem with `load_model`?

Comment: load_weights loads all the weights, the problem is that optimizer state are not weights. Just use load_model

Comment: Any other approach is way more complicated and involves studying the source code.... go for `load_model(..., custom_objects)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your comments. I will just use ``load_model``.